# Find an element by its id in the html file

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash, angular8

I have an array

```
items = [{
"id" : 1,
"name": "peter"},
{
"id" : 2,
"name": "john"}
    ...
]
```

I am trying to find an item in the html file by the id based on that, I am trying to hide and element.

It can be easily done in js file, but I am trying to see if there is an easy way to do it in html file

Comment: You question isn't particularly clear. If you want to know whether the `id` property of an object literal is mapped to the `id` property of an html element, the answer is only if you've taken steps to make that happen.

Comment: You can create a table. For example a table with 2 columns. The first column contains the id and the second column contains the name. After you search the item from the table.

Comment: @TheHeadRush  I am trying to something like <div *ngIf = "item.id == 1 && item. name == "peter"> Here in the items array, I want to see if id ==1 then the name should be peter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a template selector to the element

```
<input #myElement>
```

Then you can add a reference in your `ts` file

```
@ViewChild('myElement') myInput: ElementRef<HtmlInputElement>;
```

Or even reference the element directly in the template

```
<button (click)="myElement.focus()"></button>
```

- https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild
- https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an item, lets say its index is 2, you can do something like this in the HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let eachItem of allArrayItems; let index=i">
  <div *ngIf="i != 2">  // This ngIf will be hidden if the index is 2
     whatever logic
  </div>
</ng-container>
```